# Openpyxl - How to know current row numer in iter_rows?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
for row2 in ws.iter_rows(min_row=row, max_row=linha, min_col=coluna_min, max_col=coluna_max):

    if contador_linha == row + 1:
        # Escreve no arquivo na 2° linha com #2#
        arquivo_resultado.write(f'#2#|{contador_linha}|')
    else:
        # Escreve no arquivo na 3° linha em diante com #3#
        arquivo_resultado.write(f'#3#|{contador_linha}|')

    print(str(row2[0].row))
```

```
print(str(row2[0].row))
```

AttributeError: 'EmptyCell' object has no attribute 'row'

I tried to use row[2].row to print row number but the error break the process... I wanna know how to get the **row number** inside a iter_rows with read_only mode...

Answer (score 2):

you could access the `cell.value` for each cell in a row and concatenate them with `join()`

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    print(','.join([cell.value for cell in row]))
```

sorry for my misunderstanding. 
another way to count your rows would be:

```
for i, row2 in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row = row, max_row = linha, min_col = coluna_min, max_col = coluna_max), row):
    if i == row + 1:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

in case you want the row-number of your excel-sheet, in the enumerate, use the starting "row" there too.

The default value of enumerates second argument is 0. In case you want to have a counter for your iterable ws.iter_rows(), you could write it like this:

```
for i, row2 in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row = row, max_row = linha, min_col = coluna_min, max_col = coluna_max)):
    print(i, row2)
```

however keep in mind, that you defined the `min_row = row` in your `ws.iter_rows()`. Since i don't know which value you pass there, you won't necessarily start in row 1 of your excel.

Comment: Okay, but I need the current line **number** inside iter_row.

Comment: I have been adding it for you in the post above. Basically you could adjust the starting value of enumerate: `enumerate(iterable, start = desired_value)`. The default value of start is 0.

Comment: Nice! Thanks... better than insert a many counters.